# Finding a number in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I have an array of 20 numbers (64 bit int) something like 10, 25, 36,43...., 118, 121 (sorted numbers).

Now, I have to give millions of numbers as input (say 17, 30).

What I have to give as output is:

```
for Input 17:

17 is < 25 and > 10. So, output will be index 0.

for Input 30:

30 is < 36 and > 25. So, output will be index 1.
```

Now, I can do it using linear search, binary serach. Is there any method to do it faster way ? Input numbers are random (gaussian).

Comment: Binary search is probably the fastest you'll get.

Comment: actually, this problem is quite interesting... there is a sequence of bins in which you should check in that order.  the first thing you want to do is derive a decision tree that tells you how to go about searching to get minimal expected run time.  then use that tree to do the search.  depending on the distribution **of the 20 numbers** and the distribution of the incoming numbers, you can build this tree appropriately.

Comment: by the way, where did you get this problem?  this is an entropy compression algorithm... information theory?

Comment: @thang, No. Actually, I am a master's student and I find it during my project work on a text processing tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the distribution, you can **direct your search in a smarter way**.

Here is the rough idea of this variant of binary search:

Assuming that your data is expected to be distributed uniformly on 0 to 100.

If you observe the value 0, you start at the beginning. If your value is 37, you start at 37% of the array you have. **This is the key difference to binary search: you don't always start at 50%, but you try to start in the expected "optimal" position.**

This also works for Gaussian distributed data, if you know the parameters (If you don't know them, you can still estimate them easily from the observed data). You would compute the Gaussian CDF, and this yields the place to start your search.

Now for the next step, you need to refine your search. At the position you looked at, there was a different value. You can use this to re-estimate the position to continue searching.

Now **even if you don't know the distribution** this can work very well. So you start with a binary search, and looked at objects at 50% and 25% already. Instead of going to 37.5% next, you *can* do a better guess, if your query values was e.g. very close to the 50% entry. Unless your data set is very "clumpy" (and your queries are not correlated to the data) then this should still outperform "naive" binary search that always splits in the middle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search

The expected average runtime apparently is `O(log(log(n))`, from Wikipedia.

**Update**: since someone complained that with just 20 numbers things are different. Yes, they are. **With 20 numbers *linear* search may be best**. Because of CPU caching. Linear scanning through a small amount of memory - that fits into the CPU cache - can be really fast. In particular with an *unrolled loop*. But that case is quite pathetic and uninteresting IMHO.

Comment: +1 In my experience, interpolation search beats binary search hands-down.

Comment: -1, this is incorrect use of interpolation search.  Interp search works well if your search space is big.  This search space is only 20.  The randomness that you are given (Gaussian) is of the input number, NOT of the search space.  The method that you have outlined to pick the starting point is incorrect.  The starting point should be the bin that is most probable based on whatever statistical property you know of the incoming data.  For example, if your 20 numbers were 0 80 ... 99, then assuming uniform distribution if incoming data, you should ALWAYS start by checking the first bin!

Comment: in fact, even in the wikipedia article: *This method will only work if calculations on the size of differences between key values are sensible.*

Comment: @thang with 20 numbers, even a linear search may be faster because of CPU caching and pipelining. So that not really is an argument. He probably wants to scale up at some point. The Wikipedia statement refers to the fact that e.g. on a list of (textual) Strings, interpolation search will not work very well; although you could interpret strings as variable length numbers and try to do this kind of search, because this kind of difference is not sensible for text. Plus, note that I said "assuming uniform on 0...100" for the simple example of choosing the starting bin!

Comment: @ErichSchubert, i don't think that is it.  that is the whole point of the problem -- you have a small search space and you need to do a lot of searches.  in fact, linear searching **is not** faster even with 20 numbers.  with 20 number, the entire search space is in cache, so regardless of linear or binary, you're operating on cache.  additionally, linear search space has just as bad a chance of screwing up branch prediction (if not worse).  with binary search, you are making fewer comparisons...

Comment: @ErichSchubert, the second statement I made is with respect to your application of interpolation search.  **Assuming that your data is expected to be distributed uniformly on 0 to 100.**  I will assuming that is incoming data, not the 20 numbers, although you are not clear to this point.  If my assumption is correct, then you are incorrectly applying interpolation search.  Interpolation search assumes uniformity of the search space, not the distribution of the incoming search numbers.  In fact, interpolation search makes no assumption about the distribution of the incoming search numbers.

Comment: And this leads to my reasoning for saying that this is incorrect use of interpolation search.  Interpolation search assumes large search space **and** you know the distribution of the search space.  It **does not** utilize the distribution of the incoming search numbers.  You are given distribution of the incoming search numbers and since you know search space, by implication, you know the exact histogram of the search space.  Interpolation search only utilizes half of the information available, but in your answer, if my understanding is correct, you're utilizing the wrong half.

Comment: **He probably wants to scale up at some point.** I think this is an incorrect assumption, too.  In fact, his specific problem is somewhat canonical.  You have a lot of data, but you've managed to distill it to a handful of clusters with ordering.  Your task now is to assign new data to these clusters.  Sound familiar?  It's almost  a canonical problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing will be better than `binary search` since your array is sorted.

Linear search is `O(n)` while binary search is `O(log n)`

**Edit:**

Interpolation search makes an extra assumption (the elements have to be uniformly distributed) and do more comparisons per iteration.

You can try both and empirically measure which is better for your case

Comment: Incorrect. See my reply. If you have *some* idea of the distribution, you can do interpolation search in `log(log(n))`

Comment: It is still a variant of binary search

Comment: Yes, but it is not *the binary search* algorithm, that is available as `binarySearch` or `std::binary_search` in various class libraries, which always starts at 50%. Just like A* is not Dijkstra, albeit it is a variant of it.

Comment: I see your point, but knowing the distribution of the numbers to be searched might not be that helpful if the array that we search was generated purely random i.e. not Gaussian

Comment: No, interpolation search is not a variant of binary search. Binary search is a less efficient special case of interpolation search.

Comment: @iTech even if you don't know the *exact* distribution, interpolation search can help a lot. See, if you looked at objects 1 and 50 already, and your result was really close to that at 50, why would you go to 25 next? Try 45 next. Unless you have a really clumpy distribution (and your searches are uniform), it will still help.

Comment: @iTech If you use CDF as I suggested in my reply, it also by no means is limited to uniform distribution.

Comment: You have to add the extra computation to the algorithm complexity, which make it more cumbersome. As I suggested, they can both be evaluated empirically and whichever works *better* let it be.

Comment: so let's just examine which is faster... let's say you do get log(log(20)) with interp search, then that is about 3 iterations.  however, in each iteration, you have to do (1) a comparison and (2) a complicated calculation.  (2) is most likely more expensive than (1), but suppose they're the same, then you are doing 2*3 = 6 operations on average.  with binary search, you are doing log(20) = 5 comparisons (worst case scenario)!  which one is faster?

Comment: I totally second using binary search because it is simplicity and performance cannot be beaten !

Comment: @iTech, the performance can be improved if you tune the comparison indices as I have described to optimize for the expected # of compares.  i guess, technically, that is still binary search since at each step it divides the space into 2 sections, albeit not equal sections.  i think that worst and average cases are still O(log n), but the constant for the average case can be smaller depending on how different the distribution of the 20 number is from the distribution of the incoming number.  if you are doing the search 1 million times, it can matter a lot...

Answer (score 2):

I believe best option for you is to use [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) - it will find the first value in the array bigger than the one you are searching for.

Still depending on the problem you try to solve maybe [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) may be the thing you need.

All of these algorithms are with logarithmic complexity.

Comment: Given the description of the problem, `std::binary_search` is not suitable.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this problem is quite interesting because it is a re-cast of an information theoretic framework.

Given 20 numbers, you will end up with 21 bins (including < first one and > last one).

For each incoming number, you are to map to one of these 21 bins.  This mapping is done by comparison.  Each comparison gives you 1 bit of information (< or >= -- two states).

So suppose the incoming number requires 5 comparisons in order to figure out which bin it belongs to, then it is equivalent to using 5 bits to represent that number.

Our goal is to minimize the number of comparisons!  We have 1 million numbers each belonging to 21 ordered code words.  How do we do that?

This is exactly an entropy compression problem.

Let a[1],.. a[20], be your 20 numbers.

Let p(n) = pr { incoming number is < n }.

Build the decision tree as follows.

```
Step 1.

   let i = argmin |p(a[i]) - 0.5|

   define p0(n) = p(n) / (sum(p(j), j=0...a[i-1])), and p0(n)=0 for n >= a[i].
   define p1(n) = p(n) / (sum(p(j), j=a[i]...a[20])), and p1(n)=0 for n < a[i].

Step 2.

   let i0 = argmin |p0(a[i0]) - 0.5|
   let i1 = argmin |p1(a[i1]) - 0.5|
```

and so on...

and by the time we're done, we end up with:

```
i, i0, i1, i00, i01, i10, i11, etc.
```

each one of these i gives us the comparison position.

so now our algorithm is as follows:

let u = input number.

```
if (u < a[i]) {
   if (u < a[i0]) {
      if (u < a[i00]) {
      } else {
      }
   } else {
      if (u < a[i01]) {
      } else {
      }
   }
} else {
   similarly...
}
```

so the i's define a tree, and the if statements are walking the tree.  we can just as well put it into a loop, but it's easier to illustrate with a bunch of if.

so for example, if you knew that your data were uniformly distributed between 0 and 2^63, and your 20 number were

```
0,1,2,3,...19
```

then

```
i      = 20  (notice that there is no i1)
i0     = 10
i00    = 5
i01    = 15
i000   = 3
i001   = 7
i010   = 13
i011   = 17
i0000  = 2     
i0001  = 4     
i0010  = 6     
i0011  = 9
i00110 = 8
i0100  = 12
i01000 = 11
i0110  = 16
i0111  = 19
i01110 = 18
```

ok so basically, the comparison would be as follows:

```
if (u < a[20]) {
  if (u < a[10]) {
     if (u < a[5]) {
     } else {
         ...
     }
  } else {
     ...
  }
} else {
  return 21
}
```

so note here, that I am not doing binary search! I am first checking the end point.  why?

there is 100*((2^63)-20)/(2^63) percent chance that it will be greater than a[20].  this is basically like 99.999999999999999783159565502899% chance!

so this algorithm as it is has an expected number of comparison of 1 for a dataset with the properties specified above! (this is better than log log :p)

notice what I have done here is I am basically using fewer compares to find numbers that are more probable and more compares to find numbers that are less probable.  for example, the number 18 requires 6 comparisons (1 more than needed with binary search); however, the numbers 20 to 2^63 require only 1 comparison.  this same principle is used for lossless (entropy) data compression -- use fewer bits to encode code words that appear often.

building the tree is a one time process and you can use the tree 1 million times later.

the question is... when does this decision tree become binary search?  homework exercise! :p the answer is simple.  it's similar to when you can't compress a file any more.

ok, so I didn't pull this out of my behind... the basis is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding

Answer (score 1):

You could perform binary search using [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). These give you back iterators, so you can use `std::distance` to get an index.

Comment: There's.. `std::binary_search` too.

Comment: @Rapptz that doesn't work if the searched element is not present in the array.

Comment: @Rapptz: `std::binary_search` is next to useless.  When you do a binary search(or any search), you almost always want to know the position of the element.  All `std::binary_search` does is tell you `true` or `false`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yeah I forgot, I thought it would return an iterator to the element like the other find algorithms.

Comment: @Rapptz even if it did, it would only be useful **iff** the element was in the array. OP is looking for bounds.